# Заполнение элементов динамического массива

Tags: c++

я хочу заполнить динамический массив с помощью ввода значений через сin,но после ввода единственного значения k хотя я к примеру хочу 5 у меня происходит прекращение работы программы:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "rus");
    int n;
    int k = 0, b = 0;
    cout << "Введите n:";
    cin >> n;
    int *arr_1 = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << "Введите k:";
        cin >> k;
        arr_1[b] = k;
        b += 1;
        cout << "Коэффициенты k: " << arr_1[b] << endl;
        delete[]arr_1;

    }




}
```

Comment: `delete[]arr_1;` - ???

Comment: ну в смысле,я освобождаю память под массив,а что не так?

Comment: то есть этот массив после этой строчки Вам больше не нужен? Зачем `b`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    cout << "Введите k:";
    cin >> k;
```

Ввели

```
    arr_1[b] = k;
    b += 1;
```

И зачем тут `b`? `cin >> arr_1[i];` вполне бы работало

```
    cout << "Коэффициенты k: " << arr_1[b] << endl;
```

А теперь освобождаем память, чтоб на следующей итерации лезть в не принадлежащую нам память, а на следующей итерации освободить ее еще раз - чтоб уж запороть внутренние структуры и работу менеджера памяти наверняка...

```
    delete[]arr_1;
}
```

Сделайте так:

```
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "rus");
    int n;
    cout << "Введите n:";
    cin >> n;
    int *arr_1 = new int[n];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << "Введите arr[" << i << "]: ";
        cin >> arr_1[i];
    }
    cout << "Коэффициенты k:\n";
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        cout << "arr[" << i << "] = " << arr_1[i] << "\n";

    delete[]arr_1;
}
```

Comment: Ну, если этот ответ на вопрос вас устраивает - помечайте как принятый...

Answer (score 1):

Несколько off-topic комментариев для начала, коль скоро это C++:

1. используйте std::vector
2. используйте максимально точные по семантике типы данных, в частности, что будет, если для n будет введено значение -1?

Считывать из std::cin в std::vector можно используя итераторы, но я тут просто приведу небольшие изменения для вашего исходного кода:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "rus");
    size_t n = 0;

    cout << "Введите n:"; cin >> n;

    if (n == 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    int *arr_1 = new int[n];

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << "Введите k:"; cin >> arr_1[i];
        cout << "Коэффициенты k: " << arr_1[i] << endl;
    }

    delete[] arr_1;

    return 0;
}
```

Основная проблема в вашем коде была в удалении arr_1 в теле цикла, т.е. сразу после первой итерации массив переставал существовать и действия на нем вызывали undefined behavior. Используйте std::vector.